# How to open specific scene using local notifications and SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, usernotifications

Let's say I have GameViewController, SceneMenu, Scene1 and Scene2.

My default scene is SceneMenu and from there I can navigate between all 3 scenes.

I also implemented local notifications which contains additional information in userInfo. And I am able to successfully retrieve this information when user tap on the notification. However, I am unable to figure out how to open specific scene based on the information provided in userInfo. For example, I'd like to open dynamically Scene1 or Scene2 when user tap on the notification and when user goes to app directly, I'd like to show him SceneMenu.

Thanks for help in advance.

Here is the sample code from GameViewController.swift which opens SceneMenu and sendNotification function.

```
import SpriteKit
import UserNotifications

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    let scene = SceneMenu(size: view.frame.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
    scene.backgroundColor = .white
    
    let view = view as! SKView
    view.presentScene(scene)
    
    view.showsFPS = true
    view.showsNodeCount = true
    
    requestNotificationAuthorization()
    
}

func requestNotificationAuthorization() {
    
    let authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions(arrayLiteral: .alert, .badge, .sound)
    
    center.requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { (success, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
}

func sendNotification(scene: String) {
    
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    
    content.title = "title"
    content.body = "body"
    content.badge = NSNumber(value: 3)
    content.userInfo = ["scene": scene]
    
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 3, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "testNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    
    center.add(request)
    
}
```

}

AppDelegate.swift sample code:

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "testNotification"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    completionHandler()
    
}
```

SceneMenu.swift sample code:

```
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "testNotification"), object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] (notification) in
        guard let strongSelf = self else {
            return
        }
        guard let name = notification.userInfo?["scene"] as? String else {
            return
        }
        strongSelf.testFunction(scene: scene)
    }
    
}
```

and testFunction which I planned to use to go to specific scene (however it doesn't work and I am also not sure if this is the best way of doing it):

```
func testFunction(scene: String) {
    
    switch scene {

    case "scene1":
    print("scene1")
    let scene = Scene1(size: size)
    scene.backgroundColor = .white
    self.view?.presentScene(scene)
    break

    case "scene2":
    print("scene2")
    let scene = Scene2(size: size)
    scene.backgroundColor = .white
    self.view?.presentScene(scene)
    break

    default:
    print("nothing")
    break

    
}
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: I've updated my question with relevant code.

Comment: Ok, so you are having problem to actually receive notification while your game is in the foreground? ( `testFunction` is not run at all at foreground)?

Comment: No, I can actually receive the notification and read the userInfo. However, I'd like to display different scene based on information provided with notification.

For example, sometimes I will create notification in Scene1, and next time in Scene2. And I'd like that notification created in Scene1 goes to Scene1 when user tap on it. And when notification is created in Scene2 it goes to Scene2.

I hope this make sense.

Comment: Well I tried your code, and it works for me. I just pass correct scene name in `sendNotification(scene:)` method, then in `testFuncion` in switch, correct transition occurs. Check if you have passed correct scene name in `userInfo`. And check if you are checking for correct scene name in `switch`. You should use constants, to avoid typos.

Comment: I've tried again and it doesn't work on my end. so testFunction() will print message "testFunction" (I've added this for testing to see if it will initiate the function when user tap on notification and it does). However it will not move to Scene1 or Scene2. Instead it will display SceneMenu, which is defined in GameViewController under viewDidLoad(). I tried to pass the scene name in userInfo and use it after and also to hardcode the scene name, and it does't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242634/discussion-between-whirlwind-and-sebastijan-b).